# Is there any code formatter for spacebars in sublime text?

Tags: meteor, sublimetext2

Something that would work like the CodeFormatter package does for regular HTML, but with Spacebars would be awesome!

Answer (score 1):

There appear to be some plugins for Handlebars, which [Spacebars is built off of](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/livehtmltemplates).

> Meteor ships with a templating language called Spacebars, inspired by Handlebars. It shares some of the spirit and syntax of Handlebars, but it has been tailored to produce reactive Meteor templates when compiled.

You can search on [Package Control for Handlebars](https://packagecontrol.io/search/handlebars); it looks like [this one](https://github.com/daaain/Handlebars) is pretty popular.

Comment: That isn't a code formatter. I am looking for something that cleans up your code just like the CodeFormatter plugin. It should do indents etc. automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Really old, what I did was download https://github.com/victorporof/Sublime-HTMLPrettify and use this in Sublime Text.  Open the preferences for it and enable handlebars indentation with

```
"indent_handlebars": false, // e.g. {{#foo}}, {{/foo}}
```